# PlayerGui.QuestGui.Background.Font.Quest:5: attempt to index nil with 'WaitForChild'. How to fix this problem in roblox?

Tags: lua, local, roblox

[image: 1]

How to fix this problem in roblox

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to have any issues, have you modified the code after the error occurred?

Answer (score 0):

This is just a possibility, but your code is a server-script attempted to be run as a client. Keep this in mind while you're programming. LocalPlayer can only be accessed from a localscript, and you're trying to access it from a regular script.